# Send message to Discord channel (channel.send is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, as I see in [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), i can call `tc.send("foo");` but it's not working in my code:

```
    client.on('ready', () => {
       var tc = client.guilds.get('547536528533094401').channels.get('547537490651774987')
       console.log(tc.name) // Squad 1
       tc.send('foo') // tc.send us not a function
    })
```

In the console, I'm getting the right channel name (Squad 1), but I'm also getting

```
TypeError: tc.send is not a function
```

I guess It is not a casting problem as

```
client.guilds.get('547536528533094401').channels.get('547537490651774987').send('foo')
```

doesn't work either.

When i do `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(client.guilds.get('577240924162359312').channels.get('577240924162359321')))`

i get:

```
[
  'client',
  'type',
  'deleted',
  'id',
  'name',
  'position',
  'parentID',
  'permissionOverwrites',
  'bitrate',
  'userLimit',
  'guild',
  'members'
]
```

I'm useing discord.js@11.5.0

Comment: Hey it's a promise try it with :

    `channel.send('hello!')
      .then(message => console.log(Sent message: ${message.content}))
      .catch(console.error);`

Then you can handle the error

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(tc.type)`?

Comment: @slothiful Object

Comment: Mind posting a screenshot? It should always be a string. What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I am doing" npm install Discord "and im getting "discord.js@11.5.0" but when i do
"npm discord.js -v" i get 6.4.1

Comment: @slothiful Nevermind, that was the npm version, I'm running 11.5.0

Comment: You mention that the name is `Squad 1` but text channel names can't have spaces and capitalization is ignored. Do you mean `#squad-1`, or is that the exact output?

Comment: @slothiful Ok, I'm feeling so dumb. I was copying the General channel id instead of the #general channel id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It was a foolish mistake. I was copying the id of the **voice** general channel (`General`) instead of the **text** general channel (`#general`).

So, when trying to access the `TextChannel.send()` method it was not finding any because it was a `VoiceChannel`. (Both extending `GuildChannel`, which in turn extends `Channel`).

I am still wondering why tc.type returned Object instead of GuildChannel as I am not very into javascript's weak typing, but at least now it works.

Special thanks to [@slothiful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11321804/slothiful).